# Wordpress - Add Settings Page to own Menu Page

Tags: wordpress, settings, custom-pages

Is it possible to add a single settings page to your own created menu page?
I have a Menu Page called "Company Menu". Inside this page I want to add a Settings page for the Social Media addresses of the Company, so the moderators can change/edit the social media addresses and add more if needed. Those settings should be used page-wide / globally.

Right now I do the following:

```
function company_register_menu() {
    add_menu_page( __( 'Company Menu', 'company' ), __( 'Company', 'company' ), 'edit_others_posts', 'company_menu', '', '', 4 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'company_register_menu' );
```

Can I somehow do:

```
add_options_page()
```

to create an options page inside this menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `add_submenu_page` to add submenu page in custom menu page.

Please check the below line of code.

```
function company_register_menu() {
    add_menu_page( __( 'Company Menu', 'company' ), __( 'Company', 'company' ), 'edit_others_posts', 'company_menu', '', '', 4 );
    add_submenu_page( 'company_menu', 'Social Media Addresses', 'Social Media Addresses', 'manage_options', 'social_media_addresses', '_social_media_addresses_function');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'company_register_menu' );
```